# Accessing JSON array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, excel, sorting

So I am trying to get data from a excel file to a table, I can get the data from the excel to JSON format but now I am trying to use this data to output.

I have this function to get the excel to JSON format:

```
    var ExcelToJSON = function() {

    this.parseExcel = function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                type: 'binary'
            });
            workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
                // Here is your object
                var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
                console.log(JSON.parse(json_object));
                jQuery( '#xlx_json' ).val( json_object );
            })
        };

        reader.onerror = function(ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    };
};
```

which will output something like this:

```
const data = 
      [ { Rep:            'aa'
        , Type:           'SO'
        , Number:         '11'
        , Client:         'test'
        , Revenue:        '4025'
        , Equipment:      '-2240'
        , Share:          '0'
        , Other:          '0'
        , Date:           '15-5-2020'
        , Paidinfulldate: '10-7-2020'
        } 
      , { Rep:            'aa'
        , Type:           'SO'
        , Number:         '111'
        , Client:         'test'
        , Revenue:        '7104'
        , Equipment:      '-5334.4704'
        , Share:          '0'
        , Other:          '0'
        , Date:           '25-5-2020'
        , Paidinfulldate: '16-7-2020'
        } 
      , { Rep:            'aa'
        , Type:           'SO'
        , Number:         '111'
        , Client:         'test'
        , Revenue:        '675'
        , Equipment:      '-400'
        , Share:          '0'
        , Other:          '0'
        , Date:           '2-6-2020'
        , Paidinfulldate: '10-7-2020'
        } 
      , { Rep:            'aa'
        , Type:           'SO'
        , Number:         '111'
        , Client:         'test'
        , Revenue:        '2000'
        , Equipment:      '-1200'
        , Share:          '0'
        , Other:          '0'
        , Date:           '9-6-2020'
        , Paidinfulldate: '10-7-2020'
        } 
      , { Rep:            'aa'
        , Type:           'SO'
        , Number:         '111'
        , Client:         'test'
        , Revenue:        '770'
        , Equipment:      '-336'
        , Share:          '0'
        , Other:          '0'
        , Date:           '15-6-2020'
        , Paidinfulldate: '16-7-2020'
        } 
      , { Rep:            'aa'
        , Type:           'SO'
        , Number:         '111'
        , Client:         'test'
        , Revenue:        '0'
        , Equipment:      '0'
        , Share:          '0'
        , Other:          '15'
        , Date:           '20-7-2020'
        } 
      ]
```

But after this I want to access this data to do calculations with this in other functions, for example the revenue.

I am very new to javascript so I hope this isn't a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the array-object "ExcelToJSON" you can access the information in it by first going into the array:

```
ExcelToJSON[0]
```

That will allow you to access the elements inside the first array. You can then easily use object syntax.

```
console.log(ExcelToJSON[0].Rep)
```

Expected result from above: "aa"

An example of this using a code snippet is below:

```js
var excelToJSON =  [{"Rep":"aa","Type":"SO","Number":"11","Client":"test","Revenue":"4025","Equipment":"-2240","Share":"0","Other":"0","Date":"15-5-2020","Paidinfulldate":"10-7-2020"},{"Rep":"aa","Type":"SO","Number":"111","Client":"test","Revenue":"7104","Equipment":"-5334.4704","Share":"0","Other":"0","Date":"25-5-2020","Paidinfulldate":"16-7-2020"},{"Rep":"aa","Type":"SO","Number":"111","Client":"test","Revenue":"675","Equipment":"-400","Share":"0","Other":"0","Date":"2-6-2020","Paidinfulldate":"10-7-2020"},{"Rep":"aa","Type":"SO","Number":"111","Client":"test","Revenue":"2000","Equipment":"-1200","Share":"0","Other":"0","Date":"9-6-2020","Paidinfulldate":"10-7-2020"},{"Rep":"aa","Type":"SO","Number":"111","Client":"test","Revenue":"770","Equipment":"-336","Share":"0","Other":"0","Date":"15-6-2020","Paidinfulldate":"16-7-2020"},{"Rep":"aa","Type":"SO","Number":"111","Client":"test","Revenue":"0","Equipment":"0","Share":"0","Other":"15","Date":"20-7-2020"}]

excelToJSON.forEach(thingy =>{console.log(thingy.Revenue)})
```

You can access the elements in the second partition of the array by using:

```
excelToJSON[1]
```

And so on...

However, I would recommend looking into map if you just want to take certain parts of this array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: When I try to implement this I get an error saying it can't read for example 'Revenue' undefined.

Comment: Your question was edited after I posted this answer. You should be using data[0].revenue.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<script>
var array = [{"Rep":"aa","Type":"SO","Number":"11","Client":"test","Revenue":"4025","Equipment":"-2240","Share":"0","Other":"0","Date":"15-5-2020","Paidinfulldate":"10-7-2020"},{"Rep":"aa","Type":"SO","Number":"111","Client":"test","Revenue":"7104","Equipment":"-5334.4704","Share":"0","Other":"0","Date":"25-5-2020","Paidinfulldate":"16-7-2020"},{"Rep":"aa","Type":"SO","Number":"111","Client":"test","Revenue":"675","Equipment":"-400","Share":"0","Other":"0","Date":"2-6-2020","Paidinfulldate":"10-7-2020"},{"Rep":"aa","Type":"SO","Number":"111","Client":"test","Revenue":"2000","Equipment":"-1200","Share":"0","Other":"0","Date":"9-6-2020","Paidinfulldate":"10-7-2020"},{"Rep":"aa","Type":"SO","Number":"111","Client":"test","Revenue":"770","Equipment":"-336","Share":"0","Other":"0","Date":"15-6-2020","Paidinfulldate":"16-7-2020"},{"Rep":"aa","Type":"SO","Number":"111","Client":"test","Revenue":"0","Equipment":"0","Share":"0","Other":"15","Date":"20-7-2020"}]
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    console.log(array[i]['Revenue']);
}
console.log(array[0]['Revenue']);
</script>
```